# Mongoid embedded model not writing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've tried many solutions from different questions.
when I create a new recipe and give it attributes for its embedded model 'ilist' it doesn't save them.

Models:

```
class Recipe
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps
 field :title, type: String
 ...

 embeds_many :ilists
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :ilists,
 :allow_destroy => true,
 :reject_if     => :all_blank,
 :autosave => true
end

class Ilist
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 field :quantity, type: Integer

 embedded_in :recipe, inverse_of: :ilists
end
```

controllers:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def new
 @recipe = Recipe.new
 @recipe.ilists.build
end
def create
@recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @recipe.save
    format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
...
end

class IlistController < ApplicationController
def new
    @ilist = @recipe.ilist.build
 end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :ilists do |builder| %>

    <tr>
    <td><%= builder.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= builder.text_field :quantity %></td>
    <td><%= builder.check_box :_destroy %><%= builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Ingrediant" %></td>
    </tr>

<% end %>
...
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Once I click submit everything but the embedded documents attributes are saved. using the console and giving a recipe a few 'ilists' shows that i am rendering them correctly and that when I click edit each field shows with its correct values they just don't save. This is for a college project and help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an output of the recipe_params please

Comment: I have got it working a different way but thanks